# c# Performance slowdown while looping/iterating through a long process

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

**OVERVIEW**
I am facing performance slowdown while iterating MANY times through a calculator class.
Iterations take about 3mn each at the beginning and take longer and longer as the iteration count grows (30mn+/per process). I have to Stop the program/Restart the execution where I left it to come back to normal conditions (3mn/per process).

**WHAT I DO**
I have a scientific application that tests a set of parameters over a process. 
For example I have N scenarios (i.e a parameter combination), tested over an experimentation set, that consists in a calculator class that takes the parameters in input, processes them against T possible XP conditions, and stores the output in ORM objects, that are fired to DB after each iteration.
 In other words, Each of the N Parameters combination is passed T times trough the calculator.

```
Parameter combination : Params Set 1, Params Set 2, ...., Params Set  N
Experimental Set      : XP Set 1    , XP Set 2    , ...., XP Set T
```

So I have NxT combinations,  N and T being around 256 each, which give 65000+ iterations.

**HOW I DO IT**
I have a GUI to fix the parameter sets, and launch Background Workers (one per Parameter combination). Each Backrgound worker loads the first of the T XP sets, executes the current Parameter Set, move to next XP Set, and so on .  A report is generated after each single iteration by the calculator (i.e after each Nx/Tx) and an event is fired to populate .NET Linq/SQL ORM objects (AgileFX) and store them into an SQL Server Database.

**THE PROBLEM**
The process runs fine the first 30mn and then slowly begins to drift, each iteration taking longer and longer (Sound like a memory overflow or so...)

**HINT**
Oddly enough, an experimenter noticed very pertinently that ***the processing time grows in a linear fashion*** : +3mn more of the precedent processing time. Which comes down to an arithmetic progression (Tn+1 = Tn + 3mn)
I have a 12-Core INTEL and 24GB RAM

Comment: Determine if your .NET Application has a Memory Leak
: http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2010/11/determine-if-your-net-application-has.html

Comment: what are you asking here?? all i see is a bunch of math/text and no code or question.

Comment: @RPM :  The question is obvious and is in the title and overview : the problem is that processes that should take 3mn take longer and longer when executed in a row. All programming questions are not direct code related, it's about the design and resolution tracks

Comment: @Mitch : Nice Hint, i'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found one part of the problem, but it did not fix the issue completely :

Objects where sent to the ORM via Delegates registered by a Listener, so each Calculation Thread was still "existing" in the memory even after it has ended. 
As a colleague stated it : "Even if you move off, If I still have your address in my registers, ror me you still live in the neighborhood."

BTW, performance wizard in VS2010 works a treat. Extremely insightful and useful for monitoring overall memory performance with precision and accuracy.

**EDIT : PROBLEM SOLVED**
*The class responsible for firing background workers was keeping track of some data in a tracker object that kept growing on and on and never flushed, getting bigger and bigger. I've noticed this by closely tracking memory usage per object in VS 2010 Performance Wizard.

I advice having a clear view of objects lifecycle, and memory usage, although it can get tough when the application is big and complex.*

Comment: That's why you are supposed to unregister for an event that you are done listening with, and also set an object's internal event delegate to null when the object is done.

Comment: Also, since you are using .NET 4, take a look at the Task Parallel Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A quick suggestion, could you solve your problem through Memoization, avoiding re-calculating what should have been known results?

Also, remember that your garbage collector will not be able to do a garbage collection if you have it will find a reference to the object in some way!

Comment: I can't avoid calculation since every combination scenario is unique. Garbage collection should be quite seamless, I don't know how to "force" terminate references to some objects.

Comment: you need to null all references to it, eg object A = null;